# Can't SSH into ubuntu server after setting static IP address

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, static-ip

I have a newly built Ubuntu 22.04 server.
I have only installed the OS and ran updates.
This server is only used internally (no public access).
It has 2 NICs, but only enp2s0 is used.
When in DHCP, I get the address of 192.168.4.62 and I can SSH in just fine.
I changed /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml from

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true   
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

to

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.4.49/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.4.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.4.1,1.1.1.1]
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Everything appears correct. I can ping the static IP and the server can see the network/internet.

BUT, I can no longer SSH into this device.

Why?

=======================================

**Edit 1**:
Disable firewall and apparmor had the same results.
I didn't find anything particularly useful in the logs. This is a flat network and everything is on the same subnet.
Verbose SSH:

```
    /ssh -vvv 192.168.4.49
    OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/shawn/.ssh/config error:2
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.4.49 is address
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.4.49 [192.168.4.49] port 22.
    debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001CDB0F8B9F0
    debug1: connect to address 192.168.4.49 port 22: Connection timed out
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.4.49 port 22: Connection timed out`
```

Comment: When you try and SSH in, what exactly does it happen/if you are sshing from a Linux box, can you add "-v" to your ssh and let us know what it says?  Do the server logs show anything?  Have you tried temporarily disabling the firewall?  Have you tried temporarily disabling apparmor?

Comment: First look at the output from `ss` or `netstat` to see where `sshd is listening from. Second, check whether other systems are in the same subnet or know of the route to this system.

Comment: I will add comments above for formatting

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had 2 devices with the same IP address.
A simple solution but it cost me 2 days.
Note to self: Always double check the static IP you want to use.